# Delete array which contains key value in multi-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

How do I delete the array which contains a matching key value in a multi-dimensional array?

I am using only javascript with no frameworks.

I am parsing the following array with the following:

```
"services": [
    {
        "_id": "62473476313228338b3320cc",
        "name": "test",
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "this",
                "type": "mulDropdown",
                "_id": "624f19bbec96c92076e98095",
                "data": [
                    {
                        "_id": "6250aaa4e5d0f222d74311d3",
                        "name": "this too",
                        "hidden": "0"
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "62546392fa98b17106d35d7c",
                        "name": "this three",
                        "hidden": "0"
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "6254639efa98b17106d35d7d",
                        "name": "this4",
                        "hidden": "1"
                    }
                ],
                "hidden": "0"
            },
            {
                "isRequire": false,
                "name": "another this",
                "type": "dropdown",
                "_id": "624f3bb4fda95e5fdf978016",
                "data": [
                    {
                        "_id": "625463d5fa98b17106d35d80",
                        "name": "another",
                        "hidden": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "625463e6fa98b17106d35d81",
                        "name": "another2",
                    }
                ],
                "hidden": "0"
            }
          ]
      }
    
]


services.forEach((item, index) => {

item.fields.forEach((i, ind) => {

if (i.type == "mulDropdown") {

i.data.forEach(function (item, index) {

if (item.hidden == '1') {
delete item["name"];
```

At this point I can see the values and can remove the keys with 'delete item' but I need to delete the entire data array with something like 'delete data[2]'

I've tried various filter, splice, remove examples but I can't manage to make it work on my array.

Desired array:

```
"services": [
    {
        "_id": "62473476313228338b3320cc",
        "name": "test",
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "this",
                "type": "mulDropdown",
                "_id": "624f19bbec96c92076e98095",
                "data": [
                    {
                        "_id": "6250aaa4e5d0f222d74311d3",
                        "name": "this too",
                        "hidden": "0"
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "62546392fa98b17106d35d7c",
                        "name": "this three",
                        "hidden": "0"
                    }
                ],
                "hidden": "0"
            },
            {
                "isRequire": false,
                "name": "another this",
                "type": "dropdown",
                "_id": "624f3bb4fda95e5fdf978016",
                "data": [
                    {
                        "_id": "625463d5fa98b17106d35d80",
                        "name": "another",
                        "hidden": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "625463e6fa98b17106d35d81",
                        "name": "another2",
                    }
                ],
                "hidden": "0"
            }
          ]
      }
    
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could map thru the keys and filter the data property based on `"type" = "mulDropdown"` and `"hidden" !== "1"`.  Please note this will modify the original object. But from your example, seemed like you may be ok with that.

```js
let obj = {
  services: [
    {
      _id: '62473476313228338b3320cc',
      name: 'test',
      fields: [
        {
          name: 'this',
          type: 'mulDropdown',
          _id: '624f19bbec96c92076e98095',
          data: [
            {
              _id: '6250aaa4e5d0f222d74311d3',
              name: 'this too',
              hidden: '0'
            },
            {
              _id: '62546392fa98b17106d35d7c',
              name: 'this three',
              hidden: '0'
            },
            {
              _id: '6254639efa98b17106d35d7d',
              name: 'this4',
              hidden: '1'
            }
          ],
          hidden: '0'
        },
        {
          isRequire: false,
          name: 'another this',
          type: 'dropdown',
          _id: '624f3bb4fda95e5fdf978016',
          data: [
            {
              _id: '625463d5fa98b17106d35d80',
              name: 'another',
              hidden: '1'
            },
            {
              _id: '625463e6fa98b17106d35d81',
              name: 'another2'
            }
          ],
          hidden: '0'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

obj.services.map((s) => {
  s.fields.map((f) => {
    f.data = f.type === 'mulDropdown' ? f.data.filter((d) => d.hidden !== '1') : f.data
  })
})

console.log(obj)
```